# how to add an OnClick event on DropDownList's ListItem that is added dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have the following code:

```
        DropDownList changesList = new DropDownList();

        ListItem item;

        item = new ListItem();
        item.Text = "go to google.com";
        changesList.Items.Add(item);
```

How do you dynamically add an OnClick event to `item` so that google.com will be visited after clicking on the `item`?

Comment: probably I need `changesList.SelectedIndexChanged +=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
DropDownList changesList = new DropDownList();

ListItem item;
item = new ListItem();
item.Text = "go to google.com";
item.Value = "http://www.google.com";

changesList.Items.Add(item);
changesList.Attributes.Add("onChange", "location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;");
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare the dropdownlist

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDestination" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Destination" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Go To Google.com" Value="http://www.google.com" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Go To Yahoo.com" Value="http://www.yahoo.com" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Go To stackoverflow.com" Value="http://www.stackoverflow.com" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Second, in the code behind put this code

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlDestination.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string goToWebsite = ddlDestination.SelectedValue;
        Response.Redirect(goToWebsite);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this may help. but my question was `DropDownList's ListItem that is added "dynamically"?` thank you anyways.