# Handle event in dynamically created button in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created dynamic `textboxs` and `dropdownlist` in `gridview`. It is working perfectly. Further I want to fire event in dynamic `dropdownlist` and do some action.

```
private ArrayList GetDummyData() {  

    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();  

    arr.Add(new ListItem("Item1", "1"));  
    arr.Add(new ListItem("Item2", "2"));  
    arr.Add(new ListItem("Item3", "3"));  
    arr.Add(new ListItem("Item4", "4"));  
    arr.Add(new ListItem("Item5", "5"));  

    return arr;  
}  

private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl) {  
    ArrayList arr = GetDummyData();  

    foreach (ListItem item in arr) {  
        ddl.Items.Add(item);  
    }  
}  

private void SetInitialRow() {  

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    DataRow dr = null;  

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));  
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item   
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item   

    dr = dt.NewRow();  
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;  
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;  
    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;  
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);  

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState for future reference   
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;  

    //Bind the Gridview   
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;  
    Gridview1.DataBind();  

    //After binding the gridview, we can then extract and fill the DropDownList with Data   
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");  
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList2");  
    FillDropDownList(ddl1);  
    FillDropDownList(ddl2);  
}  

private void AddNewRowToGrid() {  

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null) {  

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];  
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;  

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0) {  
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();  
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;  

            //add new row to DataTable   
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);  
            //Store the current data to ViewState for future reference   

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;  


            for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {  

                //extract the TextBox values   

                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");  
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");  

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"] = box1.Text;  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"] = box2.Text;  

                //extract the DropDownList Selected Items   

                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");  
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList2");  

                // Update the DataRow with the DDL Selected Items   

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column3"] = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column4"] = ddl2.SelectedItem.Text;  

            }  

            //Rebind the Grid with the current data to reflect changes   
            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;  
            Gridview1.DataBind();  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");  

    }  
    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks   
    SetPreviousData();  
}  

private void SetPreviousData() {  

    int rowIndex = 0;  
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null) {  

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];  
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {  

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {  

                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");  
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");  

                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");  
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList2");  

                //Fill the DropDownList with Data   
                FillDropDownList(ddl1);  
                FillDropDownList(ddl2);  

                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1) {  

                    //Assign the value from DataTable to the TextBox   
                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();  
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();  

                    //Set the Previous Selected Items on Each DropDownList  on Postbacks   
                    ddl1.ClearSelection();  
                    ddl1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString()).Selected = true;  

                    ddl2.ClearSelection();  
                    ddl2.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString()).Selected = true;  

                }  

                rowIndex++;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {  
        SetInitialRow();  
    }  
}  

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    AddNewRowToGrid();  
}  

protected void Gridview1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {  
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];  
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");  
        if (lb != null) {  
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1) {  
                if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1) {  
                    lb.Visible = false;  
                }  
            }  
            else {  
                lb.Visible = false;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;  
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;  
    int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;  
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null) {  

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];  
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1) {  
            if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1) {  
                //Remove the Selected Row data and reset row number  
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);  
                ResetRowID(dt);  
            }  
        }  

        //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference  
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;  

        //Re bind the GridView for the updated data  
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;  
        Gridview1.DataBind();  
    }  

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks  
    SetPreviousData();  
}  

private void ResetRowID(DataTable dt) {  
    int rowNumber = 1;  
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {  
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {  
            row[0] = rowNumber;  
            rowNumber++;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: So finally, what is the question?

Comment: How to fire event in dynamically created dropdownlist in gridview??

Comment: Well, what kind of event you want to fire... Have you tried to move the cursor over the specified gridview? have you tried to click or select some of the items in your DropDownList.  This will fire the events you want.  But probably you want to know how to define a callback that get's called upon those events, right?  Finally, I continue the same, without knowing what do you want to know.+

Answer (score 0):

Might be a duplicate of question:

[how to add an OnClick event on DropDownList's ListItem that is added dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523688/how-to-add-an-onclick-event-on-dropdownlists-listitem-that-is-added-dynamically)

Please check the answer given there.

```
DropDownList changesList = new DropDownList();

ListItem item;
item = new ListItem();
item.Text = "go to google.com";
item.Value = "http://www.google.com";

changesList.Items.Add(item);
changesList.Attributes.Add("onChange", "location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;");
```

Also have you tried adding a handler to the event SelectedIndexChanged dynamically when adding the new row to the grid?